# scale pdf pages in Python/ pypdf2

Tags: pdf, scale, pypdf

I have a question related to this post with the current pypdf2 and python versions. Using this code from the Pypdf2 documentation I receive an empty page 0x0mm. scaling content works as it should.

My understanding ist that the result should be scaled content as well as page size;

Other posts show that it has worked inn the past, obviously not with the current pypdf version.

Do you have an idea?

Thanks in advance for your help.

```
from PyPDF2 import PdfReader, PdfWriter, Transformation

# Read the input
reader = PdfReader("pdffile.pdf")
page = reader.pages[0]
# Scaling the content - works
op = Transformation().scale(sx=0.7, sy=0.7)
page.add_transformation(op)

# Scaling page - returns empty page
page.scale_by(0.7)

# Write the result to a file
writer = PdfWriter()
writer.add_page(page)
writer.write("out-pg-transform.pdf")
```

Comment: PyPDF2 is deprecated. Use pypdf.